# Youtube API returns video views number always the same

Tags: php, json, youtube

I'm using Google YouTube API Ver2 to get video data, everything works good but I got the same views number "12180171" for all videos !

```
$data=@file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$video_id.'?v=2&alt=jsonc');
$obj=json_decode($data);
$video_data['views'] = number_format($obj->data->viewCount, 0, ',', ',');
```

video_id example : -0_JiSm5_EA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I faced the same problem since yesterday, and I discovered that Google has stopped gdata API (ver 2.0), you can check the below link

http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2015/04/bye-bye-youtube-data-api-v2.html

you can check this post on Stackoverflow it's pretty useful, it doesn't solve the entire problem but still appreciated effort

[Fetch video details on Youtube using API v3 in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347328/fetch-video-details-on-youtube-using-api-v3-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the video id you are using is the one included in the youtube url (for all visitors).

It seems it's not the video_id.

Check there to get the real video_id : [Youtube API - Extract video ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556559/youtube-api-extract-video-id)